# Dynamically change innerHTML of all elements to their previous siblings' values

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table which each of its columns is like this:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" id="row_ROWID" value="A_RANDOM_NUMBER">
  <div target="row_ROWID" id="div_ROWID">CHANGE_ME</div>
</td>
```

Now I need change the innerHTML of the divs from CHANGE_ME to the value of the previous input. I can do it for 1 of the divs like this:

```
$("div").html($("#div_ROWID").prev().attr("value"))
```

What I need is to change all of the divs without passing all the div_ROWIDs. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all your row divs the same class and you can easily select them all with one selector:

**Html**

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id="row_ROWID" value="A_RANDOM_NUMBER">
    <div target="row_ROWID" id="div_ROWID" class="divRow">CHANGE_ME</div>
</td>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.divRow').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).prev('input').attr('value'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('td div').html(function(){
    return $(this).prev().val();
});
```

Comment: I actually looking for "each" keyword. Sorry I have to accept the other answer.

Comment: @AliBZ So having the `each` *keyword* is a requirement of your application?

Comment: No but I simplified my question and post it here. It was too complicated to explain the real problem. Unfortunately I couldn't use your answer to solve my problem.